# JavaFX: how to temporary block the GUI

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to figure out if blocking the GUI is possible. Basically, my application (which is using the **NetBeans Platform** and **JavaFX**) has a connection to the server.

Independently on which screen the user is seeing, if the application loses the connection to the server I'd like to block everything (the users cannot open any new windows or click anywhere) until the application is connected again (it doesn't matter if that needs 5 minutes or 5 hours). Nevertheless, on the top of everything should appear an alert message (always on the top).

The java class which is listening to the server connection doesn't have any reference to JavaFX containers. That's what I actually have:

```
 public class StatusConnectionObserver implements ConnectionObserver {

        private final Led led;

        private final Label label;

        public StatusConnectionObserver(Led led, Label label) {
            this.led = led;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
            if (connected) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    led.setLedColor(Color.rgb(59, 249, 53));
                    label.setText("Connected");
                });

            } else {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    led.setLedColor(Color.RED);
                    label.setText("Disconnected");  
                });                      
            }
        }
}
```

and:

```
public class ConnectionComponent {

private Led led;

private Label label;

private HBox container;

private VBox ledContainer;

public ConnectionComponent() {
    initGraphics();
}

public Parent getView() {
    return this.container;
}

public void initGraphics() {
    //Here I set up the elements (label and Led) inside the container
}
```

Which is called here:

```
    @ServiceProvider(service = StatusLineElementProvider.class)
public class ConnectionIndicator implements StatusLineElementProvider {

    @Override
    public Component getStatusLineElement() {
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        new JavaFXUIThread().runOnUiToolkitThread(() -> {
            Scene scene = new Scene(new ConnectionComponent().getView());
            scene.getStylesheets().add(FXTheme.getDefault().getStylesheet());
            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
        });

        return fxPanel;
    }
}
```

The idea is to showing something on the top (even a simple text message) and, in the meanwhile, make the application in background more opaque.

Comment: Can you clarify the relationship between the code you have posted and your UI code? Judging by the comments you posted on the answers, `label` is not part of the JavaFX UI (so I wonder why you are  wrapping those calls in `Platform.runLater(...)`). What class is this code in, and if it has no access to the JavaFX UI, does the JavaFX UI have access to it? There must be some connection somewhere.

Comment: @James_D I updated my code

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting the issue I guess. There is an observer pattern here: somewhere presumably you instantiate `StatusConnectionObserver` and register it so that it observes some kind of `Connection` object. Why not create another implementation of `ConnectionObserver` that has access to the UI, so that it can do all the things described in the other answers, and register an instance of that with the same connection object? The whole point of the observer pattern is that multiple entities can observe the same data.

Comment: Also, this really looks like a Swing or AWT application, with embedded JavaFX, instead of an actual JavaFX application? So probably you should use Swing techniques for displaying a modal dialog and disabling the UI.

Comment: @James_D Yes, I instantiate 'StatusConnectionObserver' and register it directly in the 'ConnectionComponent'. Actually, the application runs with the NetBeans Platform, which is composed by several modules (exactly like the NetBeans IDE). JavaFX has been used only for the GUI inside the different components

Comment: @James_D You were right! I figured out that the NetBeans Platform is based on Swing. So, even if the different modules of my application have been developed with JavaFX, I needed to use SWING in order to disable the entire UI. Thank you for your tipps.

Answer (score 1):

You need a **modal** `Dialog`. Create such a dialog and show it when your connection goes down. Then use a Thread which periodically checks if your connection is back up. The time the connection comes alive kill the dialog. Since the dialog is modal it means that you can do nothing to the UI until it is resolved. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Comment: It's really similar to the solution which has been already given from the other user. Even if you use an Alert, you can do nothing on the UI, the point is how to keep it on the top of everything.

Regarding the thread, the setConnected() method is automatically called when the connection status change, so I don't need anything else to check the connection status.

Comment: But making it modal means that it is on top of everything. Also make it setAlwaysOnTop(true).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Alert` or `Dialog` components. You can style them by CSS or add custom content. Try this simplest solution:

```
Alert a = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Connection error");

public void createAlert() {
    a.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().clear();
    a.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    //*************** EDIT ***************
    a.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    a.initOwner(label.getScene().getWindow());
    //************************************
}

@Override
public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
    if (connected) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            label.setText("Connected");
            a.show();
        });

    } else {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            label.setText("Disconnected");
            a.close();
        });
    }
}
```

You can also add additional `Pane` on top of your entire `Scene`:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().addAll(applicationContent);
Pane p = new Pane();
p.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(31,31,31,0.6);");
//add Pane to root when disconnected
//root.getChildren().add(p);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
```

Comment: As I said, I don't have any reference to container or whatever, so I cannot use a.initOwner(). The solution itself could also work if it wasn't for one simple point: the application on the background is not completely disabled (I cannot click on anything, which is good, but if I try to click on it the alert is automatically minimized, instead of remaining always on the top). Do you have any tips about that?

Comment: You can use `a.initOwner()` since you have reference to `label`. To set owner just get `Window` of `label` component. To disable hiding you can set style of dialog to `UNDECORATED`. See my edit.

Comment: The label is inside a Status Bar (which is a NetBeans Platform's component). I cannot access, from there, to the main stage of my application. (I can only reach the HBox that contains the label).

Comment: Every `Node` has access to its `Scene`, so if you can reach `HBox` then call `hbox.getScene().getWindow()`.